# Trying to change the Border Color of a label

Tags: .net, vb.net, winforms, custom-controls

I'm working in VB, VS2008, winforms.  I've got some labels to create, and I'm using the BorderStyle = FixedSingle.

Is there any way to change the color of this border?  It is always defaulting to black.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

If you don't want to create a custom control you can try this:

Hook up to the Label's paint event.

```
void label1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
{
    ControlPaint.DrawBorder(e.Graphics, label1.DisplayRectangle, Color.Blue, ButtonBorderStyle.Solid);
}
```

Taken from [here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/winforms/thread/8f93eed6-f539-4503-93f8-88e17749275f) by [Andrej Tozon](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/user?user=Andrej%20Tozon)

Answer (score 13):

I combined the solutions from robin.ellis and orandov to get a result that worked the best for me.  I created a custom control that inherited the Label object and then overrode the OnPaint event.

```
Public Class nomLabel
   Inherits Label

  Protected Overrides Sub OnPaint(ByVal e As PaintEventArgs)
      MyBase.OnPaint(e)

      ControlPaint.DrawBorder(e.Graphics, e.ClipRectangle, myColor, ButtonBorderStyle.Solid)
   End Sub

End Class
```

Thanks for the help!

Comment: how to use this? `myLabel.BorderStyle = nomLabel` ?

Comment: @AdorableVB, nomLabel is a custom control, not a border style.  You would use nomLabel instead of the standard Label control.

Comment: yup, got it. created mine yesterday, but, the border is fixed. I want that `ButtonBorderStyle.Solid` when mouse hovered and `.None` when mouse Leave. code does not work, and if I use custom control, it does not apply the code either.

Answer (score 8):

I ran into this problem as well and ended up using a workaround.

Create a custom control which consists of a label wrapped in a panel.

You can then use the panel to create your border and change it's color to whatever you want.

I've found that it's a good idea (although a little time consuming) to wrap all controls in your application anyways, because when it comes to finding out you need a custom property, or change to all of your controls of that type, you can just change the base control and your entire app changes.