# Label and Panel border-color not working

Tags: c#, winforms

I wrote the following code for changing the border color of a label but it is not working. It is same as how I gave in the label properties.

```
void label1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
{
    ControlPaint.DrawBorder(e.Graphics, label1.DisplayRectangle, Color.Red, ButtonBorderStyle.Solid);
}
```

I found this code [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/987668/trying-to-change-the-border-color-of-a-label).

Comment: You've already accepted an answer.  If you have a new question, post a new question. Document it properly with your code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tried your code and it works fine. So i guess the problem is you haven't subscribed to your label `Paint` event. So you must do one of this two options:

- Select your label properties,go to the events and double click the `Paint` event.
- Add this to your Form's constructor or `Load` event:

  ```
  label1.Paint += new System.Windows.Forms.PaintEventHandler(this.label1_Paint);
  ```

Comment: Thanks... This helped I never used it so didn't knew about it.

Comment: Hi when I implement the same for panel it shows error. Error: No overload for 'panel1_Paint' matches delegate 'PaintEventHandler'

Comment: i guess your `panel1_paint` method has the wrong signature. It should be something like this: `private void panel1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)`